# Reduce the SVN repo size

Tags: svn

I have a huge SVN repo, 450K+ revisions, am trying to reduce the size of the history to just take the last couple of thousands of revisions, for example 20K and restore it in a new repo, I trI tried many way to achieve that, and non worked, below is the methods I recall that I used

1- normal dump, using the command below, it took two days,and still running, the dump size exceeded the repo size 8 times ( the repo size is 70G and before I killed the dump process the size of the dump reached 500GB)

> svnadmin dump demo2/ -r420000:HEAD > /share/svnbkup/split.dump
>   WARNING 0x0001: Mergeinfo referencing revision(s) prior to the oldest dumped >revision (r420000). Loading this dump may result in invalid mergeinfo.

2- using the same command but I used --incremental, The dump is not restorable

> svnadmin dump demo2/ -r420000:HEAD --incremental > /share/svnbkup/split.dump
>   * Dumped revision 420136.
>   WARNING 0x0000: Referencing data in revision 419907, which is older than the >oldest dumped revision (r420000).  Loading this dump into an empty >repository will fail.
>   WARNING 0x0001: Mergeinfo referencing revision(s) prior to the oldest dumped revision (r419907). Loading this dump may result in invalid mergeinfo.
>   * Dumped revision 420137.

3- I used the dump from the step above and tried to use svndumpfilter, and it did nothing,

4- I tried to restore the dump as it is,

> <<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 420000
>   svnadmin: E160013: File not found: transaction '0-0', path '/trunk/tool/test.xml'
>       * editing path : trunk/tool/test.xml ...root@lxc:/user# 
>   root@lxc:/SVN# du -sh final/
>   168K   final/

Answer (score 1):

1. Find LOWER border, which will NOT have references outside range (read warnings carefully - now you **have** to include at least from r419907)
2. Don't use `--incremental` for the first, base dump
3. Slice range, found in step 1, into small slices, and dump small ranges (second and later - with `--incremental` option) in turn - less time, in case of any error you have to re-done only one small dump

**On the rights on delirium**

Forget about historic data, transfer only HEAD in new repo

Comment: I tried the steps you mentioned, I have another dump with the missing references outside the range, but whether I started with the dump with the missing references or the dump with the bulk of the references, I receive the same error, missing paths and files, 
and if don’t use '--incremental' the dump size will sky high, which beat the purpose of the whole thing
am still new to the SVN, and don’t have much experience in it

Comment: @user3179814 - verify|repair original repo before dumping (it seems as damaged), text-dump **MUST** be bigger, than corressponding part of repo, but loaded dump have to produce less repo-size

Comment: Sorry for the late respond, I tried to restore the dump, the 5K rev dump, the size of the repo is still the same, it just reduced from 70G to 61G, I tried to run svnadmin verify, and it showed that the repo is not damaged, that is the only way I know of to check svn repo